# Crystal Report Viewer Next Page Closed sub report tab and return to main report second page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

i have a main report and tow sub reports as show On-Demand, my problem is when click on sub report
link everything is fine and first page as sub report will be shown ,but if i want to go to next page or export sub report as pdf just main report will be export. and if i want to go to next page crystal report viewer closed my sub report tab and back to second main report page
my CrystalReportViewerPage.cs class

```
 public partial class CrystalReportViewerPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = (ReportDocument)Session["Report"];
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.RouteData.Values["userId"].ToString()))
                throw new ArgumentNullException();

            var userId = Guid.Parse(Page.RouteData.Values["userId"].ToString());

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalController.Statements[userId];
            Session["Report"] = CrystalController.Statements[userId];
        }
    }
}
```

and aspx page

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CrystalReportViewerPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Mahya.ITS.CityMan.Views.Shared.CrystalReportViewerPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="CR" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.4000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Content/crystalreportviewers/js/crviewer/crv.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>

<body style="margin: auto;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto; direction: rtl; display: table" >
            <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" BestFitPage="True"
                       ToolPanelView="None"   EnableTheming="True" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="False"   HasCrystalLogo="False"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

CrystalDecisions.Web dll Version=13.0.4000.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after many hours, finally found problem. Must initial source of report viewer in OnInit instead of page_load event. So every things is fine and report source will not be refill again.

```
protected void CrystalReportViewer1_OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Page.RouteData.Values["userId"].ToString()))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var userId = Guid.Parse(Page.RouteData.Values["userId"].ToString());

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CrystalController.Statements[userId];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is correct. Mark the post as an answer